# How to mock a method call in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm fairly new to TDD and `Rspec`. I'm trying to figure out how to make sure a method is being called in test:

```
module Authentication
  include WebRequest

  def refresh_auth_token(refresh_token)
    "refreshing token"
  end
end


class YouTube
  include Authentication
  attr_accessor :uid, :token, :refresh

  def initialize(uid, token, refresh)
    @uid = uid
    @token = token
    @refresh = refresh

    # if token has expired, get new token
    if @token == nil and @refresh
      @token = refresh_auth_token @refresh
    end
  end

end
```

And here is my test:

```
$f = YAML.load_file("fixtures.yaml")

describe YouTube do
  data = $f["YouTube"]
  subject { YouTube.new(data["uid"], data["token"], data["refresh"]) }
  its(:token) { should == data["token"] }

  context "when token is nil" do
    subject(:without_token) { YouTube.new(data["uid"], nil, data["refresh"]) }
    its(:token) { should_not be_nil }
    it { YouTube.should_receive(:refresh_auth_token).with(data["refresh"]) }
  end

end
```

But its failing with:

> ) YouTube when token is nil
>        Failure/Error: it { YouTube.should_receive(:refresh_auth_token).with(data["refresh"]) }
>          ().refresh_auth_token("1/HBTNQ93otm1cSQH8kKauij3jO0kZQYfgH5J-hBtAP8k")
>              expected: 1 time with arguments: ("1/HBTNQ93otm1cSQH8kKauij3jO0kZQYfgH5J-hBtAP8k")
>              received: 0 times with arguments: ("1/HBTNQ93otm1cSQH8kKauij3jO0kZQYfgH5J-hBtAP8k")
>        # ./lib/youtube/you_tube_test.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in '

What I'm trying to do in this test, is to determine, when `@token` is nil, and there is a `@refresh` supplied, if `refresh_auth_token` is called on `initialize`. This mocks and stubs thing is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you want to use [any_instance](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class):

```
YouTube.any_instance.should_receive(:refresh_auth_token).with(data["refresh"])
```

Currently, you are checking if the class method `refresh_auth_token` is being called. It isn't, as it doesn't exist.

Next, as the code is executed in the constructor, that line won't catch the call, as the object is already created in the subject line before the spec.

This is the easiest solution:

```
  context "when token is nil" do
    it "refreshed the authentation token" do
        YouTube.any_instance.should_receive(:refresh_auth_token).with(data["refresh"]) 
        YouTube.new(data["uid"], nil, data["refresh"]) 
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, `any_instance` did the trick. I thought about calling `YouTube.new` again after `should_receive`, but it didn't work than. Now it does.